# What font is this - Honolulu Plantation Company

Tags: font-identification

[image: Honolulu Plantation Company]What font is this, in the Honolulu Plantation Company?

Answer (score 1):

A similar font is: [**aka Posse**](http://www.findmyfont.com/index.php/fonts/font-preview?fset=Dafont-1%20%2F%20%28Freemium%29&ffam=akaPosse%20-%20Regular&fid=fbe0899f9382b0b8022e444065f5dbaa&fsize=60&text=HONOLULU%20PLANTATION&wrap=2)  by akaType. Note FindMyFont is a site I work for.
[image]